# Updating graphs/tables inside a word bookmark

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have an excel file generating several graphs/tables which I want to automatically transfer to a .doc report. I want to be able to update the report several times, substituting the old graphs/tables with new ones in case that new data are provided.
My solution was to create enclosing bookmarks in the document to hold the dynamically-generated contents, which are updated  by a VBA macro in the excel worksheet.
So far, my code is capable of copying the data to the document, but it loses the "enclosing" nature of the bookmarks, which means that if I run the code a second time it will mess up the contents, creating nested tables instead of substituting the old ones with new ones. I don't know why, but it seems to work ok with charts.

These are the two functions I use to update the bookmarks, in case that the data I want to trasnfer are either charts or tables. GraphtoClipboard() and  TabtoClipboard() are custom functions that I use to format data to be sent to the document and copy to clipboard.

```
' Insert graph @bookmark
Sub InsertGraphAtBookmark(tBookmark As Object)
    Dim bmRange As Word.Range
    Dim bmName As String
    Set bmRange = tBookmark.Range
    bmName = tBookmark.Name

    'Prepare graph
    Call GraphtoClipboard

    ' Delete old
    If bmRange.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
        bmRange.InlineShapes(1).Delete
    End If
    If bmRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        bmRange.Tables(1).Delete
    End If
    bmRange.Delete

    ' Add new
    bmRange.Paste
    ReportDocObj.Bookmarks.Add bmName, bmRange

End Sub


' Insert table @ bookmark
Sub InsertTabAtBookmark(tBookmark As Object)

    Dim bmRange As Word.Range
    Dim bmName As String
    Set bmRange = tBookmark.Range
    bmName = tBookmark.Name

    'Prepare graph
    Call TabtoClipboard

    ' Delete old
    If bmRange.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
        bmRange.InlineShapes(1).Delete
    End If
    If bmRange.Tables.Count > 0 Then
        bmRange.Tables(1).Delete
    End If
    bmRange.Delete

    ' Add new
    bmRange.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=True
    ReportDocObj.Bookmarks.Add bmName, bmRange

End Sub
```

My solution is more or less the same I've seen many times on the web, but doesn't seem to work with tables. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick to something like this in Word is to figure out where `bmRange` is at the point when the bookmark should be created. Most likely, it's in the cell where the nested tables are being generated when the code runs again.

Since the bookmark needs to be around the entire table, the Range needs to be extended to include the entire table before recreating the bookmark. For example:

```
bmRange.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=True
Set bmRange = bmRange.Tables(1).Range
ReportDocObj.Bookmarks.Add bmName, bmRange
```

Comment: What's the text message of the error @EnricoCoscelli? No one memorizes the numbers... Also, if you `Select` the target `Range` after the paste, where is the selection at that time? That's key for something like this. I was guessing, based on the problem description (code creates nested tables), so knowing exactly where the range is after pasting will help.

Comment: Sorry, the error is "The Requested Member of Collection Does Not Exist". I think the problem is that there is no Table collection inside bmRange. If I skip the line giving the error and add bmRange.Select at the end, it moves the cursor before the table, where the new bookmark is.